# QtCreator. Автоматически скопировать обьявления виртаульных членов в производный класс. Можно ли?

Tags: c++, qtcreator

```
class A {
public:
virtual void virtFunc();
};

class B : public A {
virtual void virtFunc(); //можно ли горячей клавишей сгенерировать такое обьявление?
};
```

Можно ли как-то автоматически сгенерировать в классе B обьявления виртуальных функций, которые обьявлены в классе A? Автоматически сгенерировать `virtual void virtFunc();`, потому что он есть в классе A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Qt Creator 3.5.1:

Нажимаете правой кнопкой на имя класса в коде, выпадает меню, выбираем там **Рефакторинг - Вставить виртуальные методы базовых классов**. Появится окно, где мы выбираем, какие именно методы вставить. Нажимаем **ОК**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Специальной горячей клавиши под это, насколько я знаю, нет (оказывается, есть - см. комментарий @LigvestO).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Дополню, что так же это меню можно вызвать через Ctrl+Enter , когда каретка стоит на имени класса. И в обоих случаях (Через мышку и через клавиатуру) это меню отобразиться только если есть какие-то виртуальные члены в базовом классе, которые не переопределены в наследованном. Если все виртуальные члены уже были переопределены, то это меню не отобразится.

Чтобы не трогать мышь я делаю последовательность:
Ставлю каретку на имя класса -> Ctrl+Enter -> Enter -> Tab -> Space -> Enter

Comment: @LigvestO, спасибо, я не знал что там так можно